# C# Equal Tab Spacing

Tags: c#, list

So I have a C# program that collects a list of customers. The list displays Customer ID, Customer Name, and Customer Phone Number. The list is shown in a multi-line text box. My issue is, a customer is allowed to either use first and last name, or first middle and last name, and when the list is displayed, if one of the customers only put a first and last name, the phone number is literally right next to the name instead of tabbed like the others. I will demonstrate what I mean below.

[image]

Notice how Bob Anthony's phone number is off compared to Mary and John? What would I use to make sure that every line has the same space in the tabs?

Comment: Why are you using a textbox to display tabular data instead of a table?

Comment: Use a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) control.

Answer (score 2):

While some type of a data grid or list view would probably be more appropriate, if you want to keep it in string form you can use some of the [composite formatting features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) in [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) - notably the alignment flag:

```
string.Format("{0,-8} {1,-20} {2}", stuff)
```

The negative/positive indicates left/right alignment.  Note that strings aren't truncated for you, you'll have to do that if you don't already know the max width.

Answer (score 0):

You should get length of the longest item and add space after other items so that all of them be equal. By the way, I suggest you to use DataGridView for your application. Something like this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(3);
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = customer.ID;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = customer.Name;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = customer.Phone;
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has said a DataGridView is recomendable and easy to use, instead of truncating the information or padding it the user can resize the columns. If you still want to do it that way then you have to get each customer and format it accordingly:

```
var text = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var customer in Customers)
{
    var format = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}\n",
        FormatField(customer.Id,6),
        FormatField(customer.Name,20),
        FormatField(customer.Phone,10) // Might need extra formating
        );
    text.Append(format);
}
```

And to format it:

```
private string FormatField(object field, int size)
{               
    var value = field.ToString();           
    if (value.Length == size)
        return value;
    return value.Length > size
        ? value.Substring(0,size)
        : value.PadRight(size, ' ');
}
```

Depending on where you display it you will see some inconsistencies, like its not the same "view width" the characters "iii" and "MMM" even that they have the same length.